# Rewrite rule that removes query string from URL and redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Someone is creating erroneous links by adding a question mark and random characters to random pages on my website in the following format:

- www.mydomain.com/**?57237933** (only numbers)
- www.mydomain.com/folder1/**?709d0c24941** (with letters)
- www.mydomain.com/folder1/page-name/**?20?9h572** (double question mark)

I have found a block rule for robots.txt but need a stronger htaccess solution. I am looking for a htaccess rewrite rule that can remove the `?` and everything following it from any URLs, redirecting the visitor to the original URL.

I've found solutions to remove, for example, `?id=123` but when `id=` isn't there I haven't found a solution.

Comment: stopping the 'creation' in the first place would be a better solution

Comment: What's your problem with these requests, they normally do not hurt (and do not require a redirect).

Comment: I wish I could find the source of it but this is a relatively new yet persistent occurence. It's certainly off-site, my site is entirely static. I'd prefer to strengthen my on-site defence first.

Comment: so some one is visiting your site with random urls? so what, you should see my log files :-)

Comment: Hakre, the problem is that every one of these false URLs are being indexed in the search engines. Yet the content will be identical, unfortunately causing duplication penalties and confusion to my visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two rules check for the presence of query string and redirect to the no-query string version of the page:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1? [R,L]
```

Since you are worried about search engines crawling wrong version of page, consider changing to `R=301` once you've tested. Also, you might want to consider returning a 404 error to discourage the use of query strings and tell the search engines that there is no such thing as  `http://mydomain.com/page/?1234`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I changed the $1? to http://www.mydomain.com/$1? and added the R=301. Without adding the full URL it was replacing the ?1234 with the filepath.

Comment: Just remembered, according to documentation: when redirecting you need to specify a _valid URL_. You can omit the `http://mydomain.com` but you need the leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now, but I think this would be the solution to your question.

```
RewriteRule   ^([^?]+)\?.*$ $1 [L]
```

Please verify it and tell me if it was ok.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, appreciated. Unfortunately this didn't remove the unwanted ? data