# Repairing A Botched .htaccess Redirect Attempt

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've attempted answers from about 10 existing SO questions to no avail. Using Salman A's answer in [Rewrite rule that removes query string from URL and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474260/rewrite-rule-that-removes-query-string-from-url-and-redirect), I created the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1? [R,L]
```

…with the goal being to take a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?c=web
```

…and make it look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/web
```

After following Salman A's answer, the urls looked like:

```
http://www.example.com/?c=web
```

Then I messed something up while trying to strip the "?c=" part -- unfortunately I don't know exactly what I messed up -- and then I deleted the .htaccess file because I didn't want to mess anything else up. Now, even without the .htaccess file, some of the url's -- notably, the three url's I clicked while testing Salman A's answer -- still look like:

```
http://www.example.com/?c=web
```

...even though I deleted the .htaccess file. Three questions: 1) why are the changes persisting despite deleting the .htaccess file; 2) is that anything I need to worry about; and, 3) how do I modify the .htaccess file to get all the urls to look like:

```
http://www.example.com/web
```

UPDATE: this is what I was worried about http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/. If I botch a 301 redirect and new visitors go to the site, are they stuck with the botch? Is there a way to un-cache this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *"take a url like this and make it look like this"*, do you mean make it look that way to the server or make it look that way to the browser (two completely different things). See [the top part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273) for some clarification.

The answer that you've implemented makes the **server** see the request without the query string. After the URI `/index.php?c=web` makes its way through the URL/file mapping pipeline, mod_rewrite churns out: `/index.php`, removing the query string `?c=web` and finally the web server takes `/index.php` and serves it (sans query string). Of course, while all of this is happening, the browser, which knows nothing of all this mod_rewrite magic flying around, still displays the same URL that it was told to display, `http://www.example.com/index.php?c=web`, and since it's never told otherwise, that's the URL you still see.

If you want to change the URL that the **browser** sees, then you need to *externally redirect the browser to the new URL*. You can use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /(index\.php)?\?c=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%3? [L,R]
```

So when your browser requests `http://www.example.com/index.php?c=web`, this rule will match against the query string, and **redirect the browser** to the result, `/web`, thus changing the URL in the URL address bar of the browser. The browser now sees this new URL, *makes a brand new request to the server* for this new URL. You're probably going to want to change that back to what it originally was, because I'm guessing you really don't have a directory or file at `/web`. So you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

This makes it so the **server** sees `/index.php?c=web` when someone requests `/web`.

Comment: I've been studying the link you provided (along with Apache docs). I want an external redirect. I'm now experimenting via MAMP:

    http://localhost:8888/DR/index.php

New directives:

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /DR/

Adding your lines, nothing changes. Request `http://localhost:8888/DR/index.php?c=web` still loads `http://localhost:8888/DR/index.php?c=web` and still displays `http://localhost:8888/DR/index.php?c=web` in the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the crappy formatting, I had to severely truncate my response and edit important info out because of the dang character limit. What is the "proper" way to include more info here? Should I add it all to the original question? The comment formatting / character rules aren't very conducive to in-depth details. I'm trying to actually understand this as opposed to looking for a quick cut-and-paste solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @CL75 You can't format in comments, you need to edit your original question to clarify what you want. But adding my lines to your URL, you'll need to tailor my example to fit what you need. My example assumes you have **nothing** in front of the `?c=something`. If you have stuff, my example needs to be modified to include the DR in the `%{THE_REQUEST}` match.

Comment: It worked (although it still appends `index.php` for the homepage, but I think I can fix that. Thank you, if you don't mind I have a few more questions. Does `%{THE_REQUEST} ignore everything before `/index.php`? I'm trying to understand why it works the same given =`http://example.com/index.php` or `localhost:8888/index.php`. Also, should I use the `R=301` flag? If I do, is it true that this will never uncache in a user's browser unless they do so manually. I'm hesitant to create such semi-permanent changes.

Comment: @CL75 `%{THE_REQUEST}` is the first line of the HTTP request, it contains no protocol or hostname information. If the request *does* contain a protocol and hostname, that means it's a request to **proxy**, see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html